# For cycle for deduct colomns

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk

I have one problem, I would like to deduct $3 from $2 column in the file, but separately from all rows in the file and write the results for all rows divide by /n. Could you help me?
I create this, but it is not right.

```
for i  
do awk'{(NR = i , i++) print($3-$2)}'; done
```

INPUT file:

```
chr1 10 12

chr1 14 19

chr1 22 96
```

OUTPUT file:

```
2      
5      
74
```

Comment: Probably would help if you provide examples of your actual data and of the expected result.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `write the results for all rows divide by /n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
awk '{print $3 - $2}' test.txt
```

This will subtract the second column from the third colum and write the results for each line.

Answer (score 3):

No need for a loop, just do

```
awk '{ print $3-$2 }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

this line should work:

```
awk '{$0=$3-$2}7' input
```

Answer (score 1):

Since one answer has been accepted, but maybe both don't notice there are empty lines in source file, with these commands, the output will has some `0` lines.

```
awk '{print $3 - $2}' file

2
0
5
0
74
```

The script should be updated to :

```
awk 'NF>2{print $3 - $2}' file
```

Comment: There are empty lines in the edited version of the source file (not edited by OP). That said, obviously the way to go if OP cares about empty lines/0s, so +1.